# Nextjs - passing props from custom _app.js to <Navbar> component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-props

How can I pass props from here to a Navbar component that I would add under the Head component?
I already did it in the index.js page using getServerSideProps, but it doesn't seem to work in the _app.js file.

```
import "../_app.css";

import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import Head from "next/head";
import { ThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import CssBaseline from "@material-ui/core/CssBaseline";
import theme from "../theme";

export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
    React.useEffect(() => {
        // Remove the server-side injected CSS.
        const jssStyles = document.querySelector("#jss-server-side");
        if (jssStyles) {
            jssStyles.parentElement.removeChild(jssStyles);
        }
    }, []);

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <Head>
                <title>Furnibnz | Baldai Internetu ir Nemokamas Pristatymas</title>
                <meta
                    name="viewport"
                    content="minimum-scale=1, initial-scale=1, width=device-width"
                />
            </Head>
            <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                {/* CssBaseline kickstart an elegant, consistent, and simple baseline to build upon. */}
                <CssBaseline />
                <Component {...pageProps} />
            </ThemeProvider>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}

MyApp.propTypes = {
    Component: PropTypes.elementType.isRequired,
    pageProps: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};
```

Is there a better way to use a Navbar Component in every page or is this this the right way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good times when this was my biggest problem lol

For whoever really needs an answer to this:

You can't currently use getStaticProps and getServerSideProps in the _app component, so if I'm not wrong I was trying to fetch initial data (probably categories list) and pass it to a  component.
To fetch initial data at _app level, you should use getInitialProps (NextJs developers suggest to avoid using this), but be aware that using it, will stop NextJs from automatically statically optimize the pages that do not rely on any kind of fetching method (they will be server-side rendered - even a simple "about us" page that could be served as static html otherwise)

You can read more about it here: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/getInitialProps

Comment: Bruh... I still need the answer but code answer to this. Because how I do everything is pretty different from what I could find online as examples and I can't seem to solve the problem without converting all the code to whatever I see online :/

Comment: @sheptang Could you tell me what exactly is the issue you're facing? Maybe I can help you find a solution or at least clarify why you are facing the issue you are facing :)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the offer! Well, on this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68897130/combining-sign-in-sign-up-using-nextjs I asked about a specific way to use `NextAuth` and realized it's currently impossible/very difficult, so I switched to using `next-iron-session`. Everything seems to be working fine, except that on `_app.jsx`, I have my session detection via `getInitialProps` (to be able to distribute the session via props to components). For some reason, on first page load it's always `false`, even though the session exists. Whenever some router event happens, it's true.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to share the code or to create a very barebones repo that reproduces this issue and link it?

Comment: If you could share your github username, I'll add you to the repo. :)